# How to access an object's method for each object in a set?

Tags: kotlin

I'm new to Kotlin and I'm trying to figure out how to access each object's method of objects stored in a collection. For example:

```
open class Book(val title: String, val author: String) {
    companion object BookConstants {
        const val BASE_URL = "https://kbooks.co/"
    }
    open fun buildBookUrl(): String {
        return "$BASE_URL$title.html"
    }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val allBooks = setOf<Book>(Book("Book Title 1", "Author 1"),
        Book("Book Title 2", "Author 2"),
        Book("Book Title 3", "Author 3"))

    //CODE HERE to access each book in `allBooks` set and call `buildBookUrl()` on it to get each custom url string


}
```

Comment: `val urls = allBooks.map { it.buildBookUrl() }`

Comment: [There are a lot of functions in `kotlin.collections`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/index.html#functions).

Comment: @Slaw, I don't want to map it, I finally found the right function though. Thanks for the link. `allBooks.forEach { it.buildBookUrl() }`

Comment: My initial thought was `forEach`, but your wording made it sound like you wanted the result. Since `buildBookUrl()` doesn't do anything except return the result (i.e. doesn't set any state) I figured `map` may be more appropriate as you then have a `List<String>` holding each URL. The problem with `forEach` is it doesn't return anything (so you'd have to use the URL inside the `forEach`). Note you could also map each URL to its book using `associateBy` or vice versa with `associateWith` (both give you a `Map<K,V>`). Regardless, glad you found a solution.

Comment: Yea I wasn't trying to hold it in memory cause I already had a list of objects in memory. Just trying to figure out different ways to access object methods in a collection of objects. I can see why you would suggest `.map` now as the method `buildBookUrl()` returns a string, but this was mostly just a scope exercise for me.